# Configuring bash $PATH variable to find UNIX executable file

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix

I have a custom command called git-feature, which is located in a Unix executable file with the same name. I'm trying to configure the $PATH variable in `~/.bash_profile` so that it recognizes the Unix file. I updated the PATH variable to include the file's path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/git-shortcuts/
```

The `echo $PATH` command in my bash terminal produces the following result:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/myname/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/git-shortcuts/
```

But trying to call `git-feature` leads to the following error:

```
-bash: git-feature: command not found
```

There are a few similar questions on S.O., but none of the ones I found solved this specific type of issue. **Do I need to change the PATH variable differently in order for my custom command to be recognized by bash?**

Comment: Did you add execute permissions with `chmod +x git-feature`?

Comment: What happens if you run: `/Users/myname/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/git-shortcuts/git-feature`?  Is it found and executable? If not, then you've got the wrong directory on your path.  If so, there isn't an obvious reason why it would fail.

Comment: You need to re-read your profile after changing its contents by logging out and back in or doing ". ~/.bash_profile"

Comment: If its custom executable you added to PATH variable, then whether running `which git-feature` prints `~/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/git-shortcuts/git-feature` or do you see `/usr/bin/which: no somep in (path..... ) ` ??

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the PATH variable correctly.

Make sure that `git-feature` really is in that directory, that it has the executable bit (+x) set, and that the directories leading to it give you rights to execute it:

```
MYFILE=/Users/myname/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/git-shortcuts/git-feature
ls -l "$MYFILE"
chmod +x "$MYFILE"
[ -x "$MYFILE" ] && echo "File can't be executed, check directory rights"
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm still having a little trouble, though. When I add your code to my .bash_profile, I get the following error: "-bash: MYFILE: command not found" I don't know why MYFILE is being treated as a function rather than a variable.

Comment: You don't need to run this from .bash_profile, this is a one-time setup - it will add the executable bit and show you whether the command is executable, none of which needs to be run at every login.

Comment: About your error, make sure you *don't* have spaces around the `=` sign, otherwise it will try to execute MYFILE instead of assigning a value to it.